# Como faço para o input texto continuar selecionado após eu clicar enter (o enter adiciona o texto do input a uma lista de tarefas)

Tags: javascript, html, input

ListaToDo

```
<main id="base_list">

    <div id="title_list"><p id="title_text">ToDo list</p></div><!--TITLE LIST-->

    <form id="input_back" >
        <input id="add_list" type="text" placeholder="type your tasks here and press enter..."><!--INPUT TO TYPE YOUR NOTES-->
    </form>

    <div class="todo_list" id='todoList'>
        
    </div><!--ADDED LIST-->

</main>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: cria um ação para o evento `keypress` por exemplo, faz o que quer e mantem o focus no campo

Comment: beleza, valeu em.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar `.focus()` no fim sua função de inclusão, não sei como está seu script, mas acredito que trate a inclusão dos dados na lista.

Utilizando o `onkeypress` para chamar sua função, tratando nela para que execute a inclusão apenas quando seja pressionada a tecla `enter`. Caso contrario, cada tecla que pressionar enquanto estiver escrevendo irá executar a inclusão. E no fim da inclusão, chame `focus()` para seu `input`.

Desta maneira, por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('add_list').focus();
```